# How to use the same keymapping for two different (neo)vim plugins

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I would like to map "Control-Space" for two plugins I am using for neovim:

```
Plug 'gaalcaras/ncm-R' (for r files)
Plug 'bfredl/nvim-ipy' (for python files)
```

In order to achieve this for normal mode, I have tried:

```
autocmd FileType r nmap <C-Space> <Plug>RDSendLine
autocmd FileType python nmap <C-Space> <Plug>(IPy-Run)
```

Howevver, the second mapping always overwirtes the first one (for all buffers, all file types). Obviously I cannot get this to work in a file type dependent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use buffer-specific mappings:

```
autocmd FileType r nmap <buffer><C-Space> <Plug>(RDSendLine)
autocmd FileType python nmap <buffer><C-Space> <Plug>(IPy-Run)
```

Comment: This did not work for me, however, the following does: `nmap <C-Space> <Plug>(RDSendLine)` followed by `autocmd FileType python nmap <buffer><C-Space> <Plug>(IPy-Run)`